# Method must have a return type, new to coding and working on third person movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Working on third person movement and am having the error with this

```
public class Input : MonoBehaviour
{

    PlayerControls(playerControls playerControls);

    public Vector2 movementInput;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if (playerControls == null)
        {
            playerControls = new playerControls();

            playerControls.playerMovement.Movement.performed += i => movementInput = i.Readvalue<Vector2>();
        }


        playerControls.Enable();
    }


    private void OnDisable() => playerControls.Disable();

}
```

Comment: Maybe somebody can explain me what is this PlayerControls(playerControls playerControls); ? thanks

Comment: @RobertHarvey Forgive me if im wrong, but isnt that an Expression-bodied method?
Expression-bodied methods also allow `void` as return type.
E.g. `void MeMethod() => Console.WriteLine();` compiles.

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: The line `PlayerControls(playerControls playerControls);` looks like a method declaration to the C# compiler, but it's missing a return type. Of course, it's also missing a method _body_, so even if you put a return type there, you're going to get an error. It's not really clear _what_ you meant, but it's pretty obvious why you're getting an error. If you want help with this not-useful typographical error of a question, you'll need to explain what you meant with that line of code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: expression-bodied methods with a `void` return type are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your line that reads `PlayerControls(playerControls playerControls);` is not valid C# syntax. This is where the problem lies. The compiler doesn't know what you are trying to do on that line (neither do I, really), so it is assuming you are trying to make a method there.

Quick edit: If you are just trying to make a field there, just replace `PlayerControls(playerControls playerControls);` with `PlayerControls playerControls;`